# FreeNX closes display immediately after successful connect in OpenSUSE 12.2

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, nx

Upgrading from a OpenSUSE 12.1 installation with a working FreeNX server, I hit an issue with the FreeNX server on OpenSUSE 12.2, running Gnome 3.

Whenever I connect, I pass the dreaded connection phase (where I've hit most of my issues with FreeNX), and see the client prepare the display, and even see a bit of the display load. But, immediately after this, the NX client will close and show me the error:

> The connection with the remote server was shut down. Please check the state of your network connection.

Now, I know my connection, to the network, at least, doesn't have any problems. It seems like the initialization of the X session in the FreeNX connection crashes the display.

The question: How do I successfully connect with an NX client to my FreeNX server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [OpenSUSE forums](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/479062-why-do-gnome-xfce-lxde-crash-freenx-under-12-2-a.html), I found that the new openSUSE 12.2 Gnome 3 GUI uses fancier features, which cause the GUI to crash over the network.

To fix this, I have to insert an option into the `AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X` option in my `/etc/nxserver/node.conf` file. My original `node.conf` file actually had nothing in it (no un-commented lines), but I found a commented line for `AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X` on line 548. I changed it to:

```
AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X="-norender"
```

And this now enables me to see a GUI successfully when I connect with my NX client to my FreeNX server.